# Only one Imperial Assignment at a time

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I currently have 5 Imperial levels not counting ones the games give you. Yet, I only have one active assignment at a time and the other two just say "waiting..." So do I just not have enough levels yet?

Edit: My gf plays on Android and she always has all three assignments active. Maybe it's an iOS issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe we just have to wait because they are creating new ones for us. Lord Vader has a message that reads "It would be unfortunate if you lacked patience while we gather new assignments."